# Rotating words animations & durations

Tags: animation, rotation, webkit, fade, cpu-word

I am rotating some words (for some grammar rules) and some of you already nicely helped me tighten up the thing. I would however like to speed up the animation/fade even more to avoid the words overlapping one another. Also how would I go about adding another 10 words without messing up the fade?

Here is my 
HTML:

```
<span>The boy
        <div class="rw-words rw-words-1">
            <span>see<b>s</b></span>
            <span>want<b>s</b></span>
            <span>use<b>s</b></span>
            <span>find<b>s</b></span>
            <span>need<b>s</b></span>
            <span>trie<b>s</b></span>
            <span>love<b>s</b></span>
            <span>leave<b>s</b></span>
            <span>call<b>s</b></span>
            <span>work<b>s</b></span>
        </div><span id="girlWord">the girl.</span><br><br>
```

And the CSS - I have trouble understanding the animation. I understand the delays that cause the words to appear, but I don't understand where the actual fade is and which part is in/out.

```
    ./*/
    ROTATING WORDS
    /*/

.rw-words{
    display: inline;
    text-indent: 10px;
}

#girlWord {
  margin-left: 4em;  /* <-- Add space for the animated words  */
}
.rw-words span{
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto;
    color: #0f269e;
}
.rw-words-1 span{
    -webkit-animation: rotateWordsFirst 20s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: rotateWordsFirst 20s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: rotateWordsFirst 20s linear infinite 0s;
}
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(1) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s; 
    -ms-animation-delay: 0s; 
    animation-delay: 0s; 
    color: #0f269e;
}

.rw-words span:nth-child(2) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; 
    -ms-animation-delay: 2s; 
    animation-delay: 2s; 
    color: #0f269e;
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(3) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 4s; 
    -ms-animation-delay: 4s; 
    animation-delay: 4s; 
    color: #0f269e; 
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(4) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s; 
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s; 
    animation-delay: 6s; 
    color: #0f269e;
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(5) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 8s; 
    -ms-animation-delay: 8s; 
    animation-delay: 8s; 
    color: #0f269e;
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(6) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 10s; 
    -ms-animation-delay: 10s; 
    animation-delay: 10s; 
    color: #0f269e;
}

.rw-words span:nth-child(7) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s; 
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s; 
    animation-delay: 12s; 
    color: #0f269e;
}

.rw-words span:nth-child(8) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 14s; 
    -ms-animation-delay: 14s; 
    animation-delay: 14s; 
    color: #0f269e;
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(9) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 16s; 
    -ms-animation-delay: 16s; 
    animation-delay: 16s; 
    color: #0f269e;
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(10) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s; 
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s; 
    animation-delay: 18s; 
    color: #0f269e;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateWordsFirst {
    0% { opacity: 1; -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; height: 0px; }
    8% { opacity: 1; height: 60px; }
    19% { opacity: 1; height: 60px; }
    25% { opacity: 0; height: 60px; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes rotateWordsFirst {
    0% { opacity: 1; -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; height: 0px; }
    8% { opacity: 1; height: 60px; }
    19% { opacity: 1; height: 60px; }
    25% { opacity: 0; height: 60px; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes rotateWordsFirst {
    0% { opacity: 1; -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; animation-timing-function: ease-in; height: 0px; }
    8% { opacity: 1; height: 60px; }
    19% { opacity: 0; height: 60px; }
    25% { opacity: 0; height: 60px; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .rw-sentence { font-size: 18px; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px)
```

Here is jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/rh98fsom/

Comment: How do you feel with `javascript` and/or `JQuery` ?

Comment: I don't always understand it, but I don't mind using it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert, but I believe you can keep adding these and just increase each one by 2 as you have above. interested to see if anyone else has some input.  this part you can condense by putting them together, and now you can see where your animation fade in/out occurs:

```
/*enter code here*/
.rw-words span:nth-child(# ...) { 



/*enter code here*/
@keyframes rotateWords {
  0% {
    opacity: 0 ;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1 ;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; 
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in; 
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in; 
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; 
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  19% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```